# Binding to DP of DO in Resources doesn't work with no errors?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I'm trying to create a class that will manage a collection of objects that are based off of an input of a different collection of objects. The resulting collection is specific to my user interface, while the input collection is just collection of data objects (models).

I wanted to be able to bind the input collection to a property of my DataContext. So, it seemed like it would be nice to do it in XAML and not in the code behind. I tried implementing DepedencyObject and creating a DP for the input collection. I also implemented IEnumerable in my GraphPlotManager dependency object so I could bind other controls items source to it.

I've tried this:

```
<local:GraphPlotManager x:Key="plotManager"
                                 GraphObjects="{Binding GraphObjects}">
```

and with a DataContextSpy

```
<common:DataContextSpy x:Key="spy2" />
<local:GraphPlotManager x:Key="plotManager"
                                 GraphObjects="{Binding Source={StaticResource spy2}, Path=DataContext.GraphObjects}" />
```

the constructor of my plot manager is called, but the dependency property is never set or modified and no errors are shown in the output window. What gives?

Edit: here's the DP code (I used the snippet, and only added an OnChanged handler)

```
public ObservableCollection<GraphObjectViewModel> GraphObjects
{
    get { return (ObservableCollection<GraphObjectViewModel>)GetValue(GraphObjectsProperty); }
    set { SetValue(GraphObjectsProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty GraphObjectsProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("GraphObjects", typeof(ObservableCollection<GraphObjectViewModel>), typeof(GraphPlotManager), new UIPropertyMetadata(null, OnGraphObjectsChanged));

private static void OnGraphObjectsChanged(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // this code never gets hit and the Collection is still null as far as I can tell
}
```

Edit2: After will's suggestion I cranked the data binding output verbosity all the way up, here's what I got using the spy:

```
System.Windows.Data Information: 10 : Cannot retrieve value using the binding and no valid fallback value exists; using default instead. BindingExpression:Path=DataContext.GraphObjects; DataItem='DataContextSpy' (HashCode=44673241); target element is 'GraphPlotManager' (HashCode=565144); target property is 'GraphObjects' (type 'ObservableCollection`1')
```

**Update:**

It works without the spy if my manager inherits from Freezable, but not if I do not inherit freezable, even with the DataContextSpy. I'm not sure if I need the spy in this case or not. Is it possible to work without my GraphPlotManager inheriting freezable?

Comment: You should also post the DP code.

Comment: @Clemens ok I posted it, I just used the snippet in VS and added the OnChangedHandler as far as I can tell it never gets hit

Comment: The binding source (the other `GraphObjects` property) might be null.

Comment: @Clemens I checked it and it is not, I was using it for other listbox as well and it is working

Comment: First thing you need to do is turn up debug messages for databinding: http://i.stack.imgur.com/MF8i5.png Next, re-run and check the output window and see what errors are there.

Comment: @Will Ok, I cranked it all the way up from Warning->All; check the update to post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inheriting from Freezable instead of DepedencyObject allowed me to declare my GraphPlotManager in my UserControl.Resources and be able to use Bindings and ElementName Bindings.

[Leveraging Freezables to Provide an Inheritance Context for Bindings](http://drwpf.com/blog/2008/05/22/leveraging-freezables-to-provide-an-inheritance-context-for-bindings/)

I knew about this trick, but I guess I've mostly seen it regarding ContextMenus or ToolTips and didn't really realize that it would possibly be appropriate for this scenario.

Another useful class that I found was a IValueConverter that allows you to put break-points into your DataBindings to examine when they fire and what the values are.

```
public class DebugConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public static DebugConverter Instance = new DebugConverter();
    private DebugConverter() { }

    #region IValueConverter Members

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Debugger.Break();
        return value; //Binding.DoNothing;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Debugger.Break();
        return value; //Binding.DoNothing;
    }

    #endregion
}

public class DebugExtension : MarkupExtension
{
    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return DebugConverter.Instance;
    }
}
```

Source Here: [Debug Databinding Issues in WPF](http://wpftutorial.net/DebugDataBinding.html)